# Conflict problem building the Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, build

I have a problem building the spring boot application. We need to build the project with the 'lib/bin/conf' structure using the maven. I did it with another project and there is no problem. But now, a conflict occurred and an action is recommended.

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.setApplicationStartup(GenericApplicationContext.java:165)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.setApplicationStartup(org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup)'

The method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.class
    jar:file:target/OrderManager/libs/spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: file:target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory: file:target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory: file:target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport: file:target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry: file:target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar
    org.springframework.core.SimpleAliasRegistry: file:target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm using a lib named communication that is provided by our company.
This is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.artifact</groupId>
    <artifactId>ordermanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Order Manager Component</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.excample.myArtifact</groupId>
            <artifactId>communication</artifactId>
            <version>latest</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target/OrderManager</assembleDirectory>
                    <repositoryName>libs</repositoryName>

                    <configurationDirectory>conf</configurationDirectory>
                    <configurationSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</configurationSourceDirectory>
                    <copyConfigurationDirectory>true</copyConfigurationDirectory>
                    <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                    <useWildcardClassPath>true</useWildcardClassPath>

                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>com.example.artifact.ordermanager.OrderManagerComponentApplication</mainClass>
                            <id>OrderManager</id>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are mixing the versions of spring boot. In your parent you are using version 2.5.2 but in your dependencies for the actuator you are using 2.4.2... never define versions of components your self only if you know what you are doing. Furthermore why are you using the appassembler-maven-plugin for a spring boot application? Use the spring-boot-maven-plugin instead....

Comment: Thanks, I need the build as I said `bin - conf - lib` structure not a fat jar file (single with all dependencies). So, would you please give me a tutorial to configure and build the project for the told structure?

Comment: My question would be: Why not using the defaults? I would suggest to build your spring boot app via defaults and maybe afterwards using appassembler... but I'm not sure...

Comment: Thanks, my friend. After your points, I remove the version tag from the packages are related to spring. The problem still remains. I also removed the actuator, but the problem remains.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that the version of the communication library is 2.3.3.RELEASE. I set the spring boot version of the project to 2.3.3.RELEASE and the problem are solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with version mismatching with the spring boot that is used in the communication library rather than the spring boot of the main project. So, I changed the spring boot version to 2.3.3.RELEASE and the problem are solved. 
Some friends told me to exclude the spring-beans artifact. I did not do that and version changing was enough, But testing the approaches that are told on this topic, can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is already there:

> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory

Your problem is, that you've got 2 JAR files containing the same class `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory`. These are:

- `/target/OrderManager/libs/communication-latest.jar`
- `target/OrderManager/libs/spring-beans-5.3.8.jar`

You have to remove one of them. Now I don't know your project and architecture, but if you're using a company customized spring library, then you should remove the standard spring jar. Use maven's [exclude mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) for that, it is a so called transient dependency, so you didn't define it explicitly, but one of the dependencies you defined is dependending on that.

First you have to find out which dependency brings that spring-beans dependency in. Use maven's dependency tree to do that:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

You can also use [dependency analysis](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) or read about the whole [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

If you want to kick out the `communication-latest.jar` you should just remove the following in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.excample.myArtifact</groupId> 
  <artifactId>communication</artifactId>
  <version>latest</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I don't want to remove the company library, So, I tried to exclude the spring beans from our library as @Alexy Semenyuk told me, but the problem still remains. I also tried your approach, I check the dependency tree and found out that `org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.8:compile` is using this decency. I tried to exclude spring beans from this package, but The problem remains.

Comment: Do a mvn clean before anything else, because you always do an assembly in your target folder and the old JAR could be still hanging there... try that!

Comment: I did that, the problem is not solved. I did `mvn clean` and then, `mvn install`. I opened the target folder and clicked on `bin/ordermanager.bat`. The problem is not soled and the error is showing.

Answer (score 1):

For resolving this conflict you can use excludes-dependencies https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

In this case, it should be

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
```

from

```
<groupId>com.excample.myArtifact</groupId>
<artifactId>communication</artifactId>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it like the following but the problem still remains.
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.excample.myArtifact</groupId>
   <artifactId>communication</artifactId>
   <version>latest</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>